# mod_proxy incorrect redirect behaviour

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, mod-proxy

In chrome this configuration causes an infinite redirect loop and in every other browser I have tried a request for https://www.example.com/servlet/foo is resulting in a redirect to https://www.example.com/foo/ instead of https://www.example.com/servlet/foo/ however this only occurs when I do not include a trailing / at the end of the request url (i.e. http://www.flightboard.net/servlet/foo/ works just fine).

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # ...

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/servlet(/.*)?$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    # ...

    ProxyPass /servlet/ ajp://localhost:8009/
    ProxyPassReverse /servlet/ ajp://localhost:8009/
</VirtualHost>
```

The virtual host on port 443 has no rewrite rules that could possibly causing the problem, the tomcat contexts being referenced do not send any redirects, and if I change the ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse directives to:

```
    ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/
    ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/
```

everything works fine (except for the fact everything from www.example.com is being passed to the proxy which is not the behaviour I want). I'm fairly certain this is a problem with the way I have my proxy settings configured because I did log all the rewrite output coming from apache and it was all correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching from mod_proxy_ajp to mod_proxy_http seems to resolve this problem.

```
ProxyPass /servlet/ http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse /servlet/ http://localhost:8080/
```

Unfortunately this has the side effect of not passing along the ip address of the remote connection. Another alternative is to add a rewrite rule to match the url with the missing slash at the end:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/servlet/[^/]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is your problem, but ProxyPassReverse doesn't work with the ajp: url. ProxyPassReverse causes rewrites of Location: headers if they match. The headers generated by a redirect have http: URLs, not ajp:

You should be able to use:

```
ProxyPass /servlet/ ajp://localhost:8009/
ProxyPassReverse /servlet/ http://hostname/
```

i.e. use ajp: for the proxy to tomcat, but use http: for matching and rewriting
the redirect headers. The returned headers also likely have the real hostname 
of the server instead of localhost. ( although localhost works for ProxyPass ).
You can check the returned headers with 'curl -I ' to see what you need to match.

[See this answer in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236626/ajp-proxy-that-maps-internal-servlet-name-to-a-different-external-name/2925301#2925301) for some links.

( This question is a couple of months old, but I just ran into the same problem, and had a tough time searching for the anwser. )